# From excel to txt - Separate lines

Tags: python, excel, text, format

I'm doing a program where I export an excel file to .txt and I have to import this .txt file into my program. The main goal is to extract the same part from each line but the problem is that in the .txt file the lines of the excel are being made into a huge string with no /n. Do you know if there is a way to separate them within the program and if so how can I do it?

The file I'm working with can be downloaded in http://we.tl/YtixI1ck6l
and so far I was trying something like

```
ppi = []

for line in read_text:
    prot_interaction = line[0:14]
    ppi.append(prot_interaction)

result_ppi = []

for line in read_text:
    result = line[-1]
    result_ppi.append(result)
```

But since it's not formatted in lines but just in a single one I'm not getting any good results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using that file as an example, use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to parse it.

Example:

```
import csv

with open('/tmp/Model_Oralome.txt', 'rU') as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
    for row in reader:
        print row[0]
```

Prints:

```
ppi
C4FQL5;Q08426
C8PB60;D2NP19
P40189;Q05655
P22712;Q9NR31
...
P05783;P02751
B5E709;D2NPK7
Q8N7J2;Q9UKZ4
```

(BTW, the issue you may be having with this particular file is the line terminations are a CR only from a Mac Classic OS. You can fix that in Python by using the [Universal Newline](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/) mode when you open the file...)

Answer (score -1):

Excel is exporting the text file with carriage returns (\r) instead of newlines (\n).

```
ppi = []
with open("Model_Oralome.txt",'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines = lines[0].split('\r')
```

From here you can iterate through each line of lines. Since it looks like you want the value of the first column:

```
lines = lines[1:]
for line in lines:
    content = line.split('\t')
    ppi.append(content[0])
```

Comment: It is a complete waste of memory to read a large file completely to then just split on `\r`. There is a Python standard way to do this contained in [PEP 278](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/)